# Как в python сделать функцию, которая будет брать данные из двух таблиц

Tags: python, excel

Здравствуйте!

Есть формулы A=A1+...+Ai, Ai=Bi^2+Ci*Di+Ki/Li. Две таблицы, из которых нужно взять соответствующие данные [image: таблица для примера]

1. Как правильно написать функцию на python, которая будет брать соответствующие данные из таблицы, обрабатывать и выдавать результат вычислений?
2. В каком формате лучше хранить данные для простоты и скорости обработки?
3. Буду рад, если дадите ссылку на теоретическую часть, в которой это расписано.

таблица 1
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MeZw2ZsvMSLUf1cDKjZMpzb5BC_mHBRXGxvuBmf_kyM/edit?usp=sharing

таблица 2
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aeyZ0vZ6NJqThSuJ5qCsM8sJaT4D3k4lTj6OhvH7Z5k/edit?usp=sharing

Данная формулы служит для расчета выбросов от двигателей автомобилей.
Существует три вида периодов теплый, холодный и переходный.
В зависимости от периода различается время работы: t1=1 мин, t2=10 мин и t3=5 мин соответственно. 
Время работы двигателя, например Tраб1=25 минут.

В зависимости от мощности различается объем выбросов: чем мощнее двигатель, тем больше он выбрасывает в атмосферу загрязняющих веществ.

Примем, что для таблицы 1 значение в ячейке С4 записывать как Tab1C4 и т.п.

Я не могу понять как мне сделать, чтобы я,например, выбрал период, который мне необходим, например теплый. 
Затем выбрал мощность двигателя, например 21-35. После этого время работы двигателя, например 25 минут.

Затем по формуле M= (Траб1*Tab2C5 + Траб1*Tab2D5 + Траб1*Tab2E5 + Траб1*Tab2F5 + t1*Tab1C4 + t1*Tab1C5 + t1*Tab1C6 + t1*Tab1C7 + t1*Tab1C8)*10^6 получил готовый результат вычислений.
Опять таки данные из таблицы часто не меняются, но не хотелось бы их хранить в самой программе. Возможно, лучше их хранить в каком-то другом формате.

Comment: Модуль `pandas` Link: https://habrahabr.ru/post/202090/

Comment: да, как уже сказал коллега @Alban, на Pandas это делается в несколько строчек и в 95% случаев без циклов. Если выложите примеры входных данных в виде текста/CSV/Excel и выходную матрицу с кратким пояснением что есть `Bi, Di, Ki, Li, etc.`,  то я мог бы набросать рабочий пример

Comment: Добавил пояснения